npm run build with an old service account json file does not build new code. [firebase cloud functions]
I have an old service account configured in my admin app like this.
 const serviceAccount = import("./../../serviceaccountdetails.json");
const firebaseApp=admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as admin.ServiceAccount),

When I type npm run build after I make changes the changes do not reflect when I make new changes. I need this service account details to generate signed image urls in host.
 const fileRef=bucket.file(filepath);
          const signedUrlPromise:GetSignedUrlResponse=await fileRef.getSignedUrl({
            action: "read",
          expires: "03-09-2491",
       }); 
        const imageUrl=signedUrlPromise[0] as string

When I commented the service account lines above, make changes and run npm run build the changes reflect when I run npm run serve.
Like this:
 //const serviceAccount = import("./../../serviceaccountdetails.json");
const firebaseApp=admin.initializeApp({
 // credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount as admin.ServiceAccount),

